# Add dynamically components to a Custom Dialog in Android

Tags: android, dialog, dynamically-generated, customdialog

I'd need your help to do something in Android, in the following the use case.
I have created a custom dialog in Android, whose layout is:
*dialog_threshold.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/ic_media_route_on_03_dark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:background="#FFFFBB33"
        android:contentDescription="@string/set_target" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_threshold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layout_threshold">

        <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/targetSelected"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/threshold_operator_spinner"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text=""
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/threshold_val"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in the Activity, when I click on a specific button, I have something like this, to create the custom dialog:

```
setThreshold_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DiseaseActivity.this);
                //Inflate the custom layout
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_threshold, null);

                //Set title for dialog
                mBuilder.setTitle("Set thresholds for your target");
                //Define the spinner inside your custom layout
                final Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) mView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_threshold); //because it doesn't exist in the main layout, but only in the custom layout
                //Define the ArrayAdapter
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DiseaseActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.threshold_choices));
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

                if (!mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Choose a threshold option")) {
                    String ThresholdSelection = mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                }
                mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        if ((dialog2 != null) && dialog2.isShowing() && !mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Choose a threshold option")) {
                            dialog2.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(true);

                        } else {
                            dialog2.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

                //Set the positive and negative button for the custom dialog
                mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        disease.setThreshold(mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

                        if (!mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Choose a threshold option")) {
                            Toast.makeText(DiseaseActivity.this,
                                    mSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            setInterval_button.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }
                });
                mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                dialog2 = mBuilder.create();
                dialog2.show();
                dialog2.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);

            }
        });
```

What I want to do now is to add dynamically other components (like EditText or TextView) to the above Dialog before is it shown.
How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

just create your custom view >> find the parent(in which viewgroup you want to add) >>> and add it. **eg:-**

```
mView.addView(new TextView(ActivityContext),LayoutParamss);
mBuilder.setView(mView);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Do I have to add just these two rows of code and it works? Could you please give me more details?

Comment: I didn't understand sorry - could you please help me?

Comment: @Giulio .. i mean,, you need to create a `View` first.eg:- `EditText edit = new EditText(context);` or TextView or whtvr.. Than find the parent view group ( eg:- `mView.findViewById`) where you want to add that view. then simply call `yourParentView.addView(your new view);`. thats it.

Comment: what about view ID and click listener?

Comment: @Manny265  In that case Create the view using Object not anonymous,, and set a TAG to the View so that you can find the view later and u can set setClickListener also.

Comment: what about adding a layout that has been designed in XML and you want to inflate multiple instances of it on the Dialog? @SRBbans